# How to switch firestore queries in stream builder in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have 3 different queries to use on 3 different sets of conditions in `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` but not able to do so.
Below is the code

```
Query query;
if (a==b){
query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection1');
}

else if (c==d){
query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection2');
}
else if (e==f){
query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection3');
}
```

**Inside Widget Build**

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

    stream: query.snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
      if (!snapshot.hasData){
        return Text("Loading");
      }

      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){

            String names = snapshot.data.documents[index]['name'];
            List steps = List.castFrom(snapshot.data.documents[index]["steps"])




            return NameCard(names: names,steps: steps);

          });
    },

  )
```

I tried to implement the query with the stream builder, but not able to do so. if there is only one query it works perfectly fine. but when I tried to switch queries depending upon the conditions it does not work, it gives error of `null snapshot`

how should I achieve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
stream: query.snapshots()
```

Try defining the stream separately and then assign it to StreamBuilder.

```
Stream stream;

if (a==b){
    stream = Firestore.instance.collection('collection1').snapshots();
}
else if (c==d){
    stream = Firestore.instance.collection('collection2').snapshots();
}
else if (e==f){
    stream = Firestore.instance.collection('collection3').snapshots();
}
```

Comment: Hi @defnotadi, The above thing resolved my issue to some extent. But I need to do pagination with this now, should I proceed further. can you please take a look at my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371422/what-is-stream-equivalent-of-querysnapshot/63371473#63371473